# Transfer Autodesk Forge App to another user

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are reorganising the accounts in my company and I was wondering:

Is it possible to transfer an existing Forge app from my account to the account of a co-worker? I could not find the option in the https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to send an email to 'Forge Transfer <forge.transfer @ autodesk . com>' with the details of the transfer request.

Requester account email
Application Client ID
Current owner account email
Receiver account email
Date of transfer

The person operating the transfer will request consent from each party before transferring the app.